# Angular 2 trying to create interface for the expected API response

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

I am expecting the following example JSON response from API, and I am trying to make an interface for it.

```
{
  types: [
    {
      id: 1,
      contents: [
        {
          id: 1001,
          perishable: 0
        },
        {
          id: 1002,
          perishable: 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is how I am trying to define the interface, but I am not sure if I am doing this right.  Basically, the response I get back is "types" which is an array of objects, and each object inside it has an array called "contents".  Also, how to say something is an array of objects?

```
export interface Types {
  id: string;
  contents: Array<any>;
}
```

Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `any` if you want, but you can be more specific:

```
interface Content {
    id: number;
    perishable: number;
}

interface Type {
    id: number;
    contents: Content[];
}

interface Response {
    types: Type[];
}
```